# Crop layer in Caffe without DummyData

Tags: python, caffe, conv-neural-network, ncsdk

i'm trying to implement a CNN in caffe to use with the Neural Computing Stick by Movidius but i have some issues.
I want to crop some intermediate output, but i can't use DummyData to give the reference blob to the crop-Layer, since it's not supported, is there another way to crop the shape without using dummyData layers( or input-Layers)?

Comment: can you use a Python layer? what layers can you use?

Comment: I can't use Python Layers. I can use : Conv (but only 3x3 with groups), deconv, slice, crop, concat, innerproduct. pool,

Comment: can you imement a new layer?

Comment: Nope, because the model needs to be compiled by a movidius tool and so they have limited support to this layers, and a little bit more ( acitvations)